# Super Street Fighter IV: Arcade Edition Missing?

Tags: steam, super-street-fighter-iv, street-fighter-iv, ultra-street-fighter-iv

I purchased both *Street Fighter IV* and *Super Street Fighter IV: Arcade Edition* before the *Ultra Street Fighter IV* came out on Steam.

The last time that I played them, there were separate games in Steam. Now, there is only Ultra SFIV and there is no SSFIV Arcade Edition anywhere, not in my library, not even in the Steam store.

I installed SSFIV and none of the extra stuff that comes with the Arcade Edition is in it. What the heck is going on?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I now have both SSFIV and the ultra edition in my Steam library. So yes, I suppose it is, thanks

Comment: Could you explain how you got both SSFIV and Ultra SFIV in your Steam library? I only have Ultra. Thanks.

Comment: Oh gosh. I really have no idea. All I know is that I purchased SSFIV, then the Arcade Edition. Both before the Ultra Edition came out. And now suddenly I have both the regular version and the ultra version. You can see both of them in my library here: http://imgur.com/VmvAI0k

Comment: Ah. It looks like you have SFIV and USFIV, not SSFIV and USFIV. Ultra is an upgrade to Super, which is why it overwrote it.

Comment: Oooooohhhhhhh so the arcade edition upgraded my SFIV to SSFIV. It all makes sense now.

Comment: Actually, the Arcade Edition was an update to SSFIV. You have to remember that SFIV and SSFIV are two different games. Sounds to me like you bought SSFIV:AE after buying SFIV. Steam would have added it as a separate game, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole SFIV series is a little overwhelming, but the problem appears to be that you're getting *Street Fighter IV* confused with ***Super*** Street Fighter IV.

*[Street Fighter IV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_Fighter_IV)* was released in 2009, and despite their similar sounding names, is a different game to *[Super Street Fighter IV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Street_Fighter_IV)* (2010).

To make matters more confusing, Capcom released several updates to *Super Street Fighter IV*:

- *Super Street Fighter IV: Arcade Edition* (2011) was the first of these (and itself had several updates applied to it known as '2012' and '2014', respectively).
- *Ultra Street Fighter IV* (2014) is the latest update to *Super Street Fighter IV*.

So basically: ***Street Fighter IV*** is one game, and ***Super Street Fighter IV*** (aka *Super Street Fighter IV: Arcade Edition* and *Ultra Street Fighter IV*) is another.

From the image you've posted, it's clear that Steam has kept your original *Street Fighter IV* purchase, but updated your *Super Street Fighter IV* purchase to the new name: *Ultra Street Fighter IV* (they're the same game, after all).

With regards to your missing costumes(?), if you purchased the original game through *Games for Windows Live*, then they're not available once you've migrated over to Steam. You can still play your GFWL version without Steam, though. [Read more here](http://www.polygon.com/2014/5/27/5755742/super-street-fighter-4-arcade-edition-dlc-lost-games-for-windows-live-steam).

Comment: Downvote. Interesting!

Comment: Seems like a very good answer to me. And my Ultra Street Fighter IV turned out to be my SSFIV, so all is well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's normal for there to be just one SSFIV in your Steam Library. I also purchased all the SF DLC'S and have one game in my Library.

The Ultra Edition is the last update and should be the default when you open your game. The others, like Arcade are not needed anymore because all the content is transferred into Ultra.

The only bug you have is that you can't see the "extra stuff". Maybe a reinstall will help or Verifying your game data in Steam?

Comment: So they completely removed the Arcade Edition from Steam?

Comment: no they just show you the newest purchased start button. If you just have the original than you have 1 button with the Original conten. If you purchased the just arade than you see arcade button but the content is the Original +arcade. And if you got Ultra than the button showes the Ultra logo and is content of Original + arcade + Ultra

Comment: I have both the arcade and original versions and I only have the original version button

Comment: oh ok could you check your account info what you purchased and what is in your library

Comment: Super Street Fighter IV Arcade Edition Complete Pack is listed under licences and subscriptions. Street Fighter IV is listed there as well, separately.

Comment: sorry sound like a big bug... i would contact the support

Comment: What is the best way to do so? Through email or...?

Comment: there is an online support side on the steam webpage.

Comment: @Kecoey This answer is completely wrong. If you bought SSFIV, it was merged with Ultra Street Fighter IV under the same ID. So launching Ultra Street Fighter IV will actually launch SSFIV, and if you want to upgrade, you'll have to purchase the digital upgrade

Comment: Yes, I tried launching the Ultra Edition and the menu said SSFIV Arcade Edition